# Splitting chain into data.frame with from and to fields

Tags: r, string, strsplit

I have vectors looking like `var a %->% var b %->% var c %->% var a`. The `%->%` denotes arcs. I want to split those vectors in `data.frames` of the form:

```
   from    to
1 var a var b
2 var b var c
3 var c var a
```

I found two versions which both seem overlycomplicated.

Version 1: with a `for` loop. Does what I want but is fairly complicated

```
v <- "var a %->% var b %->% var c %->% var a"
v <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(v, "%->%")))
links <- data.frame(from = character(length(v) - 1), to = character(length(v) - 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for(i in 1:length(v) - 1) {
  links$from[i] <- v[i]
  links$to[i] <- v[i + 1]
}
```

Verison 2: I found a solution using `sapply` which removes the `for-loop` but the `<<-` is a bit dangerous I think:

```
sapply(1:(length(v) - 1), function(i) {links$from[i] <<- v[i]; links$to[i] <<- v[i + 1]})
```

Are there simpler options to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the whole columns at once:

```
v <- "var a %->% var b %->% var c %->% var a"
v <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(v, "%->%")))

data.frame(from = head(v, -1), to = tail(v, -1))
#    from    to
# 1 var a var b
# 2 var b var c
# 3 var c var a
```

`head(v, -1)` is a nice way to write `v[-length(v)]` (all but the last element of `v`), and `tail(v, -1)` is the parallel way to write `v[-1]` (all but the first element of `v`). You can use the `[` versions if they seem clearer to you:

```
data.frame(from = v[-length(v)], to = v[-1])
# same result
```